# How can I combine two lists into one long list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have two lists in coloumns 1 and 2. I need coloumn 3 to be of the format one dash two.

For example:

[image]

Column C will need to repeat all values of A and B.

I would prefer a formula for this is possible, if not then I could use VBA. Also, my data is not as simple as ABC and 123.

Comment: Do you need a Cartesian product (set) or "outer join" as result?

Comment: I dont think either of them are applicable. I have two coloumns of data which I need to combine as above.

Comment: Well, I'll try to ask different: If your first column has 10 rows and your second col. has 15 => does your result has 10x15 rows? Or your example is wrong and you only want to merge them so that => 10 + 15 = 25 row?

Comment: It will have 10x15 rows :)

Comment: I see, this result is called the Cartesian product: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "[Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)" or "outer join".

The solutuion as VBA. Copy the following code into the right-hand side of the Visual Basic Editor. You will see that your macro now has a name "cartesianproduct": ([Source](http://tootrickybyfar.blogspot.com/2010/02/creating-cartesian-product-in-excel.html))

```
Sub cartesianproduct()
Dim startrange As Range

range1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select First Range", Type:=8)
range2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Second Range", Type:=8)
Set startrange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select where you want to put it", Type:=8)

array1 = [range1]
array2 = [range2]

startrange.Select
For i = 1 To UBound(array1)
    For x = 1 To UBound(array2)
        z = z + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(z, 0).Value = array1(i, 1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(z, 1).Value = array2(x, 1)
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

I have also found [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/654871-how-generate-all-possible-combinations-two-lists-without-macro.html) a solution as a formula (not tested!):

> =IF(ROW()-ROW($F$1)+1>COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B),"",INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW()-ROW($F$1))/COUNTA(B:B)+1)) & **" - "** & INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$1),COUNTA(B:B))+1))

I have only added  **" - "** between both values ...

Comment: The IF statement is exactly what I needed. Thank you, this will save me hours in future work :)

Comment: Glad to help, Kevin, you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another formula:  Enter in C1 and fill down until you get blanks:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Col_A,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/COUNTA(Col_B))+1) & "-" &INDEX(Col_B,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,COUNTA(Col_B))+1),"")
```

I used dynamic names to refer to the column data; you may want to change that:

```
Col_A   refers to:  =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))
Col_B   refers to:  =OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since duDE already proposed one solution with VBA, I'd like to show another one with Javascript.

You can easily manipulate Excel by coding Javascript with the help of one tool named [Funfun](https://www.funfun.io/1/#/home). Here's the core code:

```
<script>
var column1 = new Array();
  for(var i=0; i<$internal.column1.length; i++){
   column1[i] = $internal.column1[i]
  };
var column2 = new Array();
  for(var i=0; i<$internal.column2.length; i++){
   column2[i] = $internal.column2[i]
  };
var added = $internal.add;
console.log(added);
var output = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<$internal.column2.length; i++){
   output[i] = column1[i] + added + column2[i];
  };
  console.log(output);
$internal.result = output;
```

$internal is an API provided by Funfun that helps you get access to data in Excel spreadsheet. You can change the data and its area in Setting. The following is the Setting of this function:

```
{
"add": "=C2",
"column1": "=A2:A9",
"column2": "=B2:B9",
"result": {
    "Type": "Output",
    "Address": "=D2:D9"
}
```

With a single click of the function, all data and results will be loaded to the spreadsheet. Just as the following picture shows:
[image: Screenshot]

Last but not least, Funfun also provides a website version, with which you can write your own function more cozily. The [link of this function](https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5a70676f9f659277176dc8ce)

Hope it helps :)